# What are $\omega_1$ (Omega 1) and $\omega_2$ (Omega 2) in the reliability output from R?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, reliability, latent-variable

I read this [very useful article on omega reliability coefficients](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245920951747) and have since been toying around with it in R (using the `reliability` function from the `semTools` package). However, one thing that I'm still confused by is this part of the output, which is outlined in the article:

[image]

From what I've seen, `omega` and `omega2` never seem to vary, and from what the article says these are both supposed to be $\omega_u$ coefficients. I tried looking through the `reliability` documentation and found this explanation as to why they are both included:

[image]

However, I'm still a bit confused by this definition. What are dual loadings in this case (is this another name for cross-loadings)? What are "method factors"? When these values are different, what do they say about the reliability of the items? Answers with simple explanations are preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question a long time ago, but now that I know more about reliability, I can answer my original question. The $\omega$ coefficients $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are different in the following ways:

- The $\omega_2$ coefficient can be viewed as the *unconditional* reliability, where it does not account for differences in multi-dimensionality. If for example there are [cross-loadings](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2022.923877/full) (items which have at least some moderate loadings on more than one factor, the "dual loadings" that I was confused by before) or [method factors](https://youtu.be/aiRcRqyjUrI?si=xCHaz9WR8h5YcppS) (uniquely explained latent variable variance from a complicated factor structure), this coefficient will differ from $\omega_1$.
- The $\omega_1$ coefficient can be viewed as the reliability after controlling for other factors, or *conditional* reliability. If the factors in the model do not have any multi-dimensional aspects, then $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ will be the same.

It appears the [updated documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/semTools/versions/0.5-6/topics/compRelSEM) indicates that this function will in any case soon be defunct in replacement for a more complete function called `compRelSEM` which automates some of the selection process previously required in the `reliability` function for reasons outlined below:

> **Reliability**
>
> The original reliability function was suboptimally
> designed. For example, AVE was returned, which is not a reliability
> index. Also, alpha and several omega-type coefficients were returned,
> including the original formula that was in appropriate for models with
> complex structure. Some features could be controlled by the user for
> one but not both types of index For example, alpha for categorical
> indicators was returned on both the observed and latent-response
> scales, but this was not an option for any omega-type indices. The
> omegas differed in terms of whether the observed or model-implied
> covariance matrix was used in the denominator, but alpha was only
> computed using the observed matrix. These inconsistencies have been
> resolved in the new `compRelSEM` function, which returns only one
> reliability index (per factor, optionally total score) according to
> the user's requested features, for which there is much more
> flexibility. Average variance extracted is now available in a
> dedicated AVE function.
>
> **Higher-Order Reliability**
>
> Originally, composite reliability of a single
> higher-order factor was estimated in a separate function:
> `reliabilityL2`. It is now available for multiple higher-order factors
> in the same model, and from the same `compRelSEM` function that
> estimates reliability for first-order factors, using the `higher=`
> argument to name higher-order factors in the fitted model.

While now the new function automatically returns the "correct" coefficient, one can obtain them manually by setting the argument `return.total=TRUE`, which gives $\omega_2$, while giving $\omega_1$ otherwise in a single composite factor structure.